# How to get a single record for each row in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and want to display desired output.
Table

```
Dbname size devicepath
Db1.   100. Emc#123
Db1.   100. Emc#123av_2
Db1.   150. Emc#145av
Db1.   150. Emc#145av_4
Db1.   100. Emc#156av
Db1.   100. Emc#156av_1
```

Desire out put:-

```
Dbname size devicepath
Db1.   100. Emc#123
Db1.   150. Emc#145av
Db1.   100. Emc#156av
```